# Small container with only one character no centering correctly - Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, containers, center

Small container with only one character no centering correctly, with or without padding setted to 0.

If I reduce the font size will render centered, but with default text size no

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.green,
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
  width: 20.0,
  height: 20.0,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  child: Text(
    '+',
  ),
)
```

[image: Result of green container]

Update: 
With icon instead letter behave exact same.
[image]

If I change the size from 20 to 40: 
[image]

Code

```
Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            child: RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: 3,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.expand_less,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Update 2: With Fitted works with icon:
[image]

```
Container(
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color,
            ),
            child: FittedBox(
              child: RotatedBox(
                quarterTurns: 3,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.expand_less,
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce your issue. Your code works exactly like you expect. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ZdKcl3p.png Your issue may be coming from something else in your code. Likely because your green dot is a decoration and your text is a widget, and they are affected differently.

Comment: Any clue on what I can check? I can't believe for you works fine

Comment: It might to help to share more of the surrounding code where you are using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not reproduce this. But I assume that your default font size is too large for the container. You can try to wrap the Text in a ***FittedBox***, so it will adapt to the container:

```
return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.green,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      width: 20.0,
      height: 20.0,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      child: FittedBox(
        child:Text('+')
     ),
);
```

Comment: This upped a little bit the plus sign but is not completely centered

Comment: This is the result with FittedBox https://i.imgur.com/5FXwIC0.png

Comment: Check 'flutter doctor'. On which branch are you?

Comment: I was thinking... It won't be the fonts? I use font Futura-Medium...
My current branch is 
Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.657], locale en-US